# Automatically fixing un-closed HTML tags in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, tidy

I'm trying to convert HTML pages to Markdown using the reverse-markdown Ruby gem. Unfortunately it fails with:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:95:in `rescue in parse': #<REXML::ParseException: Missing end tag for 'img' (got "td") (REXML::ParseException)
```

The source contains some `IMG`, `INPUT`, etc. tags which end with `>` instead of `/>`.

I've tried the tidy_ffi gem:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(TidyFFI::Tidy.new(Nokogiri::HTML(page).to_html,
        :numeric_entities => 1,
        :output_html => 1,
        :merge_divs => 0,
        :merge_spans => 0,
        :join_styles => 0,
        :clean => 1,
        :indent => 1,
        :wrap => 0,
        :drop_empty_paras => 0,
        :literal_attributes => 1).clean)
```

but that made no difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show some samples of the HTML please.

Comment: At which point do you get the error? Show us the relevant code as well, please

Comment: Where is the HTML coming from? A markdown processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse-markdown actually assumes the markdown processor produces well-formed XHTML. If yours doesn't, you may want to try the [html2markdown](https://github.com/29decibel/html2markdown) gem. It parses using Nokogiri, and is likely more robust (disclaimer: I have not used it).

Answer (score -2):

<del>I made a gem that excerpts html: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/auto_excerpt  maybe you can use that or look at the code it uses to do this? Not sure if that answers the question here.</del>

Actually I just noticed you call Nokogiri::HTML twice: `Nokogiri::HTML(TidyFFI::Tidy.new(Nokogiri::HTML(page).to_html`

I'm not sure if the error you're getting is coming from Nokogiri or TifyFFI though.

Comment: I think this is not relevant at all. OP seems to know how to handle HTML.

Comment: His use of Nokogiri is legal. He parses the document to have Nokogiri do some fixups, converts it to HTML again, and tries to get TidyFFI to work its magic, which will return HTML again. Finally, he reparses it with Nokogiri into a document. It's unconventional, but that's OK. It just doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Correct. But, I was saying if the error was coming from the call to Nokogiri::HTML() then the first HTML conversion might be the issue, _before_ it gets parsed by TidyFFI.